# Contouring a mesh and assigning magnitude arrows in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mapping, mesh, contourf

[image: this is the mesh]

I want to assign vector to a contourf graph, in order to show the direction and magnitude of wind. 
For this I am using `contourf(A)` and `quiver(x,y)`, where as A is a matrix 151x401 and x,y are matrices with the same sizes (151x401) with magnitude and direction respectively.

When I am using large maps i get the position of the arrows but they are to densily placed and that makes the graph look bad.
[image: after quiver]

The final graph has the arrows as desired, but they are to many of them and too close, I would like them to be more scarce and distributed with more gap between them, so as to be able to increase their length and at the same time have the components of the contour map visible.

Can anyone help , any pointers would be helpful

Comment: Am i right, that the arrows in question are saved in the matrices x and y? If so did you try to not plot the whole matrices but substructures? e.g. `x(1:50:60000)`. If i am not mistaken this should show each 50th element of your x-matrix til you reach your 60000 element (which is more or less 151:401) :D

Comment: @The Minion, The  x and y matrices represent values of wind speed and wind direction, is it possibly to clarify what you mean by plot the substructures of them?

Comment: Could you post the code how you use quiver? Cause if i understand it corectly you use it for constructing vectors with the components (x,y). Where do you draw them? in 1 axis? if so you should be able to change `quiver(x,y)` to `quiver(x(1:step:lastelement),y(1:step:lastelement)`. Here step is the number of arrows you want to skip and lastelement the coordinate of the last element so size(1)*size(2) = 151*401=60551.

Comment: @TheMinion , I use contourf(A), hold, quiver(x,y), i have attached the resulting pictures if that helps

Comment: Did you try to change x,y as i said? If so what was the result like? I haven't used quiver myself, thats why my comment was just a guess which could work. When i read that you do join them into your `contourf` i think the dimensions won't fit. Another possibility would be to create an array/matrix which has the same size as x,y and which has ones where you want to show the arrow, and 0 otherwise. THen you could do elementwise multiplication, which result you could use in your `quiver`

Comment: @TheMinion I tried it it does not work unfortunately, the x,y are corresponding to each point of the contourf part thus they give vital information about the figure.
I would like to create a mesh with some embedded arrows- directions in the figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i know its been a long time since the question was asked, but i think i found a way to make it work.
I attach the code in case someone encounters the same issues

```
[nx,ny]= size(A) % A is the matrix used as base
xx=1:1:ny; % set the x-axis to be equal to the y
yy=1:1:nx; % set the y-axis to be equal to the x
contourf(xx,yy,A)
hold on, delta = 8; %delta is the distance between arrows)
quiver(xx(1:delta:end),yy(1:delta:end),B(1:delta:end,1:delta:end),C(1:delta:end,1:delta:end),1) % the 1 at the end is the size of the arrows
set(gca,'fontsize',12);, hold off
```

A,B,C are the corresponding matrices ones want to use